# Is {Z, CZ} an universal quantum gate set for diagonal gates with eigenvalues +1 and -1?

Tags: quantum-computation, quantum-information

Consider diagonal quantum gates with eigenvalues $\pm 1$, i.e. all diagonal elements are either $+1$ or $-1$.

Can these gates always be decomposed into a finite number of Z and controlled-Z gates?

My gut feeling says yes, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Let $n$ be the number of qubits. Since $Z$ and controlled-$Z$ gates all commute, only a total of $2^{O(n^2)}$ unitaries can be implemented with them, yet there are $2^{2^n-1}$ unitaries $U$ with $\pm 1$ on the diagonals ($U$ and $-U$ are considered the same unitary). This means that there is at least one $U$ that cannot be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The $CCZ$ gate with $3$ qubits is not implementable with $Z$ and $CZ$ gates. In particular, the determinant of the matrix of the $CCZ$ gate is $-1$, but all $Z$ and $CZ$ gates have determinant $1$ on $3$ qubits.

In terms of $8\times8$ matrices, we have
$$
CCZ = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&&\\
&1&&&&&&\\
&&1&&&&&\\
&&&1&&&&\\
&&&&1&&&\\
&&&&&1&&\\
&&&&&&1&\\
&&&&&&&-1
\end{bmatrix}, 
Z^{(0)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&&\\
&-1&&&&&&\\
&&1&&&&&\\
&&&-1&&&&\\
&&&&1&&&\\
&&&&&-1&&\\
&&&&&&1&\\
&&&&&&&-1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
Z^{(1)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&&\\
&1&&&&&&\\
&&-1&&&&&\\
&&&-1&&&&\\
&&&&1&&&\\
&&&&&1&&\\
&&&&&&-1&\\
&&&&&&&-1
\end{bmatrix}, 
Z^{(2)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&&\\
&1&&&&&&\\
&&1&&&&&\\
&&&1&&&&\\
&&&&-1&&&\\
&&&&&-1&&\\
&&&&&&-1&\\
&&&&&&&-1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
CZ^{(0,1)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&&\\
&1&&&&&&\\
&&1&&&&&\\
&&&-1&&&&\\
&&&&1&&&\\
&&&&&1&&\\
&&&&&&1&\\
&&&&&&&-1
\end{bmatrix}, 
CZ^{(0,2)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&&\\
&1&&&&&&\\
&&1&&&&&\\
&&&1&&&&\\
&&&&1&&&\\
&&&&&-1&&\\
&&&&&&1&\\
&&&&&&&-1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
CZ^{(1,2)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&&\\
&1&&&&&&\\
&&1&&&&&\\
&&&1&&&&\\
&&&&1&&&\\
&&&&&1&&\\
&&&&&&-1&\\
&&&&&&&-1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$